# full jpg image is not showing up in browser

Tags: html, image, jpeg

I have just encountered a strange situation.  I have some basic html:

```
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="774">
<tr>
    <td align=center valign="top">
        <br />

        <a href="../../images/backlarge.jpg" target="_blank">Click here to see larger view of scorecard</a><br />
        <img src="../../images/back_01.jpg" border="0" /><br />
        <img src="../../images/back_02.jpg" border="0" /><br />

        <br />

        <img src="../../images/front1.jpg" border="0" />
        <img src="../../images/front2.jpg" border="0" />
        <img src="../../images/front3.jpg" border="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and for some reason only 1/2 of the front2.jpg image shows up in the browser.  When i view it from disk, the image is perfect but for some reason when i upload and view in a browser it only shows 1/2 the image:

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you post the html code? According to you the problem has to do with the image, noth the html code.

Comment: i thought it might be an html issue . . but as mentioned it was just a corrupt image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uploading it again. There might have been some problems with the upload.

Comment: Probably an FTP ascii vs binary issue, you may want to read this when you have time to further avoid this. http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/ftp_for_beginners/#ASCII_versus_Binary

Answer (score 1):

I would use FireBug as a starting point, to see if there are any CSS styles being applied to the image at runtime.

Other than that, I think it's hard to tell what the problem might be without viewing the live page ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded image to disk and I only see 1/2 the image. It gives me gray in the other half. I would check the resolution of what you expect the image to be, checking I get W443 pixels by H192 Pixels. I would re-do the image. I doubt its a HTML problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have also suffered with the problem and have fixed it by adding the image to the `images` folder, and then updating the `src` of the `<img />` to be; `http://localhost:hostno/folder-where-the-website-stored/images/imagename.jpg`

Comment: This would be a solution if the image wasn't showing up at all, but as it is, this indicates an upload problem rather than the wrong path.